# Google App Script - WebAPP - Returning HTML on doPost doesn't work. doGet is fine

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my simple App Script. the doPost returns nothing. But if code to Post to return a UIApplication then it works file.

Any idea about how to send HTML output from doPost ?

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
   var form = app.createFormPanel();
   var flow = app.createFlowPanel();
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox"));
   flow.add(app.createSubmitButton("Submit"));
   form.add(flow);
   app.add(form);

   return app;
 }

 function doPost(eventInfo) {
   /* if i uncomment UiApp section then it works fine, But i want to send HTML, then the reponse is blank */
   /*var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 

   app.add(app.createLabel("Form submitted. The text box's value was '" +
       eventInfo.parameter.textBox + "'"));
   return app;*/
   /* the following returns just blank page */
   outText = "<html><body><h1> Received Text = " + eventInfo.parameter.textBox+"</h1></body></html>";
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(outText);
 }
```

So the question is how to sent HTML via doPost ?. Looks like if the doGet retuns UiApp then doPost has to return UiApp. Is this restriction or am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is correct; there is no way to mix HtmlService and UiApp in one script like this.

Edit: Let me explain further. When UiApp calls doPost, it does not respect the response unless it is a UiApp. However, if you set the form's action to be the script url explicitly, it will respect the response, be it UiApp or HtmlService, and completely replace the page. There is no way to show both UiApp and HtmlService in the browser at once though.